# Upgraded to Tensorflow 2.5 now get a Lambda Layer error when using pretrained Keras Applications Models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I followed this tutorial to build a siamese network for my problem.
I was using Tensorflow 2.4.1 and now upgraded

This code worked wonderfully before

```
base_cnn = resnet.ResNet50(
    weights="imagenet", input_shape=target_shape + (3,), include_top=False
)

flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)
dense1 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
dense1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense1)
dense2 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense2)
output = layers.Dense(256)(dense2)

embedding = Model(base_cnn.input, output, name="Embedding")

trainable = False
for layer in base_cnn.layers:
    if layer.name == "conv5_block1_out":
        trainable = True
    layer.trainable = trainable
```

Now each resnet layer or mobilenet or efficient net (tried them all)
throws these errors:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.convolution_620), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'stem_conv/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 48) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
```

It compiles and seems to fit.

But do we have to initialize the models somewhat differently in 2.5?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. Can you share complete imports and keras version details to replicate your issue? Meanwhile can you install `pip install tf-nightly` and try again?

Comment: You should not mix `Tensorflow` and `keras`. You should import all your libraries from `tensorflow` as `from tensorflow import keras`, then your issue may be resolved.Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 thanks, I always import everything from tensorflow.keras to keep version consistency. 
I haven't found the bug, but restarting and clearing the session the kernel sometimes worked. I also just reverted to 2.4.1 most of the time

Comment: That's good to hear. In `TF2.5`, i have executed your code with out any issues. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 yeah that's funky, I am thinking that the old models and stuff got stuck in the graph sometimes, that's why restarting the kernel helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the main reason for your issue as it's not reproducible generally. But here are some notes about that warning message. The traceback shown in your question is not from `ResNet` but from `EfficientNet`.

Now, we know that the `Lambda` layer exists so that arbitrary expressions can be used as a `Layer` when constructing **Sequential** and **Functional** API models. `Lambda` layers are best suited for simple operations or quick experimentation. While it is possible to use Variables with Lambda layers, this practice is **discouraged** as it can easily **lead to bugs**. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

x_input = tf.range(12.).numpy().reshape(-1, 4)
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((4, 2)), name='w')
bias = tf.ones((1, 2), name='b')

# lambda custom layer
mylayer1 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights),
                                                           bias), name='lambda1')
mylayer1(x_input)
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (lambda1), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'w:0' shape=(4, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.753139  , -1.1668463 ],
       [-1.3709341 ,  0.8887151 ],
       [ 0.3157893 ,  0.01245957],
       [-1.3878908 , -0.38395467]], dtype=float32)>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ -3.903028 ,   0.7617702],
       [-16.687727 ,  -1.8367348],
       [-29.472424 ,  -4.43524  ]], dtype=float32)>
```

It's because the `mylayer1` layer doesn't trace the `tf.Variables` directly and so that those parameter won't appear in `mylayer1.trainable_weights`.

```
mylayer1.trainable_weights
[]
```

In general, `Lambda` layers can be convenient for simple **stateless computation**, but anything more complex should use a **subclass Layer** instead. From your traceback, it seems like there can be such a possible scenario with the [`step_conv`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/efficientnet.py#L326) layer.

```
for layer in EfficientNetB0(weights=None).layers:
    if layer.name == 'stem_conv':
        print(layer)
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object..
```

Quick surveying on source code of [tf.compat.v1.nn.conv2d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L2173-L2292), lead to a [lambda expression](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L560) that might be the cause.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, this seems like a similar error. 
I am guessing, because as in the discussion with TFer2, that the recompiled model kinda lingered in the graph, hence restarting the kernel and clearing the session fixed that for me. really weird. But may have been a leftover from that and a later lambda layer. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here there is no need to revert back to `TF2.4.1`. I would always recommend try with latest version because it addressed many of the performance issues and new features.

I was able to execute above code without any issues in `TF2.5`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model


img_width, img_height = 224, 224
target_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)


base_cnn = ResNet50(
    weights="imagenet", input_shape=target_shape, include_top=False
)

flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)
dense1 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
dense1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense1)
dense2 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense2)
output = layers.Dense(256)(dense2)

embedding = Model(base_cnn.input, output, name="Embedding")

trainable = False
for layer in base_cnn.layers:
    if layer.name == "conv5_block1_out":
        trainable = True
    layer.trainable = trainable
```

Output:

```
2.5.0
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
94773248/94765736 [==============================] - 1s 0us/step
```

As per @Olli, Restarting and clearing the session the kernel has resolved the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree, I also always try to use the most recent versions of any libraries and stay up to date. This was part of a homework though and I really had to get it to work, so for this one I just reverted. M. Innat may have found the issue, maybe a leftover from a previous model lingered in the graph, which is why restarting and clearing the kernel fixed it. So wasn't related to the version after all :-S

Answer (score 0):

pip install tensorflow==2.3.0 , worked for me instead of tf 2.5
I was facing the issue related to using Lambda layer